# use keyword as identifier in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the `class` keyword as a function identifier in a namespace like:

```
namespace X {
   export function class( ... ) { ... }
}
```

The namespace itself is extending a function (`function X ( ... ) { ... }`).

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to call your function `class`?

Comment: Seriously consider why you need to name something `class`. Might want to use one of the many online thesauri to find alternate words.

Comment: No serious need, I was just playing with the language and wanted to try to create a shortcut to a function that has 'class' in its name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in TypeScript. You'd have to somehow declare a quoted name in a namespace, but there is no syntax for doing that. It's also impossible to declare a type named `class`, so you're blocked in two different ways.

You could write `(<any>X)['class'] = class { ... }` if you just needed this to be present at runtime and didn't need any type system features.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it an answers the question as asked, but I found a workaround to the issue. I posted it in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is name a method `class` this is a pretty big no no across programming languages.  `class` is what you would call a reserved word: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word

You could call the method "Class" instead and will have better results I think.

Comment: Quite a few languages let you quote keywords to make them identifiers, like F# and Scala. It's useful when the source language has different identifier rules to the compilation target, like typescript does.

Comment: Interesting, so I could call a function "if" or "then" if I wanted to? Seems kind of illogical.  I do recognize the difference in identifier rules... Still struggling to get the point though as @MikeMcCaughan mentioned.

Comment: Yes you could define an `if` function. In F# you could do: `let \`\`if\`\` x = printfn "%A" x`, although it's more useful for consuming things from other languages with different reserved keywords. For example to call `Thread.yield` in scala you have to use `Thread.\`yield\`()` since `yield` is a keyword in scala but not in java.

Comment: C♯ also allows to prefix a keyword with a '@' to use it as an identifier

Comment: Yes, I could name it Class, but I wanted to try to keep the javascript convention

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this.

```
interface I {
   (foo: Bar): Baz
   class(foo: Bar): Baz
}

const X = (function (X: any) {
   X.class = function (foo: Bar) { ... }
   return <I>X
})(function (foo: Bar) { ... })
```