# How can I declare a type for dot-prop-immutable's delete function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use the npm package dot-prop-immutable in conjunction with TypeScript. The package doesn't seem to include type definition, neither did I find some on DefinitelyTyped.

Therefore I set out to write my own declaration like this:

```
declare module "dot-prop-immutable" {
    export function get(o: Object, p: string): any;
    export function set(o: Object, p: string, v: any): Object;
    export function delete(o: Object, p: string): Object;
}
```

For the get/set functions this works like a charm. However, with the delete function I get the following errors from the TypeScript compiler:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:21
    TS1003: Identifier expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:29
    TS1005: ')' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:40
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:48
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:49
    TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:20
    TS7010: '(Missing)', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:28
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'o'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/@types/alltypes.d.ts:11:28
    TS2703: The operand of a delete operator must be a property reference.
```

The last one suggests that "delete" is a reserved keyword and the compiler is not able to interpret it as a normal function name.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use keyword as identifier in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105536/use-keyword-as-identifier-in-typescript)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using back-ticks? I would try that, as well as updating to the latest Typescript release.

```
export function `delete`(o: Object, p: string): Object;
```

Comment: When using backticks the ts compiler says "Identifier expected. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature".
I'm already on ts v 2.3.2.